# How to freeze camera when the game is paused in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So recently I started coding my first FPS game. I experienced a problem with my pause menu. The problem is when I have my game paused my mouse is still controling the camera and when I want to press some buttons in menu camera keeps following my mouse. I searched for solution to this problem on web, but I haven't found the solution (even my code is similar to some I've found).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;



public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool gameIsPaused;
    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;
    

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        { 
           
            Pause();
        }
       


    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;

        gameIsPaused = false;
    }
    void Pause()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        gameIsPaused=true;
        
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }

    public void LoadMenu()

    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu");
    }

    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Debug.Log("Quitting game...");
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the need for `static` on your `bool gameIsPaused` field?

Comment: Because I want to easily check from other scripts whether the game is paused or not (idk if u get me)

Comment: You probably need to disable the camera or at least disable the setting that allows it to follow your input device, e.g. your mouse. Did you read the official documentation for the camera: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html? Properties are described here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html

Comment: Do you have a script attached to your camera that makes it follow your mouse? You'll probably need to disable that while the game is paused. Can you show how the camera follows the mouse?

Comment: @ewerspej it's in answer below

Comment: When using `static` in Unity beware - [thar be dragons](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/DomainReloading.html).   See also _[Details of disabling Domain and Scene Reload](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfigurableEnterPlayModeDetails.html)_.  **TL;DR:** depending on how Unity is configured, the next time I click **Play** the game will immediately pause if care is not taken.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is to update the camera according to the pause conditon. like so:

```
public class CameraRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public isGamePaused; // changed from outside when you pause/unpause the game
    void Update()
    {
        if (isGamePaused) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with `gameIsPaused` (usual code convention naming to state is a bool would be `isGamePaused` :)) is that until you set it to true in the menu the camera will keep moving, so you may need to set the boolean to true  at the time the menu pops up.

Even its not the suited case for static variables, if you want to check the pause state of your game from the camera script, you can do so like this:

```
public class CameraRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public isGamePaused; // changed from outside when you pause/unpause the game
    void Update()
    {
        if (PauseMenu.gameIsPaused) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

`static` stands for static in memory, so the variable value can be checked anytime from anywhere with `ClassName.staticVariableName`. With this I mean that as long as you set the `PauseMenu.gameIsPaused` variable at the times in the code where you´d like you should be able to make it work, by working I mean freeze/unfreeze the camera at the exact moment you want.

Comment: Thank you very much it helped (I used this second option with my boolean still in static form) :)

Answer (score 0):

Your static PauseMenu.IsPaused is fine and a good way to do it although I usually put something like that on a GameManager class. You can find a Unity Singleton pattern online so you can start having PauseMenu.Instance.XXX so it's easy to access anything you need. That being said, you need to find the script controlling your camera and check the PauseMenu.IsPaused. Most likely you have a script attached to your camera, and all you generally need to do is find the Update() function and just do: if (PauseMenu.IsPaused) return; to stop it from working.